# Server receives only a part of data that sent?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

The issue is not seems to be in `post_max_size`. I tryed to change the value of it in `.htaccess` with no success. There's a quite strange behavior, for some reason there's always only 1001 entry (JavaScript is sending 1562)  in `$_POST` array, the rest just cuts off.

Here is how it looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [phrase_position] => 1
        [phrase_text_en] => Yes, this is Sunset Boulevard, Los Angeles, California.
        [hero_id] => 91
        [substrate] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [phrase_position] => 2
        [phrase_text_en] => It\'s about five o\'clock in the morning.
        [hero_id] => 0
        [substrate] => 0
    )

...

[1000] => Array
    (
        [phrase_position] => 1001
        [phrase_text_en] => Gordon Cole?
        [hero_id] => 0
        [substrate] => 0
    )

)

THE END!
```

On JavaScript side everything is fine. I checked the length of data (1562) array and I can see in Firebug console that every single element was sent as well.

What could it be?

**PS:**
I'm sending data via `jQuery.post`.
Server nginx, PHP v5.3.3, Wordpress

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

Here's the JavaScript part:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    traditional: false,
    data: {serial_data: serial_data, eno_ajax_serial_action:action},
    dataType: "xml",

    success: function (xml, textStatus) {
        ...
    },

    url: "/wp-admin/post.php?post="+post_id+"&action=edit",
    type: "POST"
});
```

Also tryed `jQuery.post`, the same thing.

Comment: Send your [phrase_text_en] as a string in array element. Put it inside quotes.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan, it is a string. It's just how PHP's `print_r()`  displays arrays

Comment: Are you sure you're running PHP 5.3. *3* ? If you were running something slightly newer, I'd say you're running into [`max_input_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).

Comment: @DCoder, yes. `phpinfo()` says `PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15`. But I will try to change the value of `max_input_vars`

Comment: You're welcome. Though I wonder if having that many variables in a single form is a good idea at all :)

Comment: @DCoder, It's not a contact form ;) It's subtitles editor for admins only. So there could be a lot of subs